# Remove rows where fields contain null values

Tags: sas

I have the following data set

```
col1 q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 
a    -  2  1  2  2
b    - -   -  -  -
b    1 2  -   -  - 
d    3 -  -  -   -
```

I want to apply a condition in SAS that allows me to delete the cases where all the columns (q1 through q5) are nulls. I would like to see this:

```
col1 q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 
a    -  2  1  2  2
b    1 2  -   -  - 
d    3 -  -  -   -
```

Comment: It's generally preferred to show the steps you have taken, rather than just asking for code to be written for you. If you need a place to start you might want to read up on some of the following: `if`/`where` (to limit the rows), `nmiss` (a function to count missing values), `sum` (which will only return missing if all its arguments are missing) and variable lists `of q:` or `of q1-q5` (to pass several variables to a function)

Comment: You should also attempt to use professional language - `wanna` is not an appropriate word for a SO question.  `Want to` is correct.

Comment: @Joe Fixed the title, and while I was at it, made the language more appropriate so it would not detract from the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most elegant solution I've been able to find for this is:

```
data want;
  array q[5];
  set have;
  if max(of q[*]) = . then delete;
run;
```

**Step-by-step**

- `data` statement sets up the output dataset
- `array` statement initialises a 5 element array named `q`
- `set` statement brings in the input dataset. Because the input dataset has variables named `q1`...`q5`, these are populated into the array.
- `if`  statement: in SAS any numeric value is greater than missing, so any case where the maximum is missing implies all values of `q` are missing. The `max(of q[*])` syntax simply brings back the maximum of all (* used to denote all) elements of the array `q`. `delete` removes the qualifying observations before they can be loaded to the output dataset.
- `run` statement - data-step boundary

**Without Array**

Thanks to SRSwift

```
data want;
  set have;
  if max(of q:) = . then delete;
run;
```

**Using the n function**

Thanks to Joe:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if n(of q:);
run;
```

As Joe explains in his comment, `n` counts the non-missing values, and an `if` statement followed by a condition only allows observations to pass into the output dataset if that condition is true (or a non-zero integer). In the case of all missing, the `n` function returns zero, the condition is not met and the observation is removed.

To illustrate this, here is the input dataset again, with an `n` column added:

```
col1 q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 n 
a    .  2  1  2  2  4 
b    .  .  .  .  .  0 
b    1  2  .  .  .  2 
d    3  .  .  .  .  1
```

Comment: You can skip the array and just go with `max(of q:) = .`

Comment: After I'd written all that stuff out about arrays I'll just add yours as a footnote, great answer @SRSwift

Comment: You can also just use `n`:  `if n(of q:) = 0 then delete;` or even `if n(of q:);` since it will delete when 0 and not delete when >0.

Comment: Yes, I have to admit your solution is the most elegant of the three, but I would probably comment it up a bit so it could be easily understood by the majority of users. I knew there would be a single `if` statement approach (without `then`) in there somewhere!

Comment: I tend to feel `n` is a good solution here even without documentation (better than `max` which works but is not clearly doing what it normally does), because `n` is a concept commonly understood in SAS to do exactly this [indicate the number of nonmissing values], even if the user isn't familiar with the data step function; it's the same idea as in `PROC TABULATE` or `PROC MEANS`.  That said, I will never disagree with adding comments and documentation to anything :)